# Prove that if $n$ is odd or if $4$ divides $n$ then $\sigma(n) < n^{3/2}$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if $n$ is odd or if $4$ divides $n$ then $\sigma(n) < n^{3/2}$

Not sure what to do here.  I think you have to look at both cases ($n$ is odd and then $4$ divides $n$) or if there is another way.

Thanks

Comment: You should write your question in the question body. The title is supposed to be descriptive (even though it can contain questions) and the question body should definitely contain the question.

Comment: Note that this is false for $n=1.$ I'm just saying.

Answer (score 2):

You do not give any background, so there is no knowing what you are supposed to do. However, Ramanujan initiated a certain method in 1915. Paper shortages forced some of the article to be cut off. So the method for the sum of divisors function was rediscovered by Alaoglu and Erdos in 1944, with the name Colossally Abundant Numbers.

Taking your exponent gives a result that is not entirely satisfactory, as they get
$$  \sigma(n) \leq 3 \cdot \left( \frac{n}{2} \right)^{3/2}   $$
with equality only at $n=2.$ The trouble is $2^{3/2} = 2.8284... < 3.$

However, the very next in the sequence gives
$$  \sigma(n) \leq 12 \cdot \left( \frac{n}{6} \right)^{5/4}   $$
with equality only at $n=6.$
As a result, $ \sigma(n) < n^{3/2}$ for all $n \geq 3.$

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function where it is called $\sigma_1,$  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number   and finally my answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79927/which-n-maximize-gn-frac-sigmann-log-log-n/79987#79987

My best guess is that you are expected to go through the Alaoglu Erdos Ramanujan argument for exponent $3/2$ and show that the result is stronger if $n$ is restricted. As this is the first, well, interesting exponent, there are not that many steps. Yes, now that I think of it, that is the way. You need to know the basic fact from Hardy and Wright, that
$$    \frac{\sigma(n)}{n^{3/2}}   $$
goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. As a result, the maximum is achieved. In particular, the maximum is achieved somewhere for odd $n,$ I suppose at $n=1,$  and the maximum is achieved for multiples of four, probably at $n=4.$ I should emphasize that your part of the argument is entirely elementary, it really is. Oh, as $3/2$ is rational, the maximum occurs at only one value of $n.$